# Lua - getting all after word

Tags: string, search, lua

There is if statement like this:
`if( reciewed_message == "video " ) then`

I need to get all text after `'video'` into a string.

For example, for string `reciewed_message == "video some music video"` i need to get `some music video` from `reciewed_message` to use as parameter to search

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.match` with captures:

```
s="video some music video"
print(s:match("video (.*)$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.find` followed by a `string.sub`.

`string.find` searches the string, and finds the starting and end position of the first query that it is given.
`string.sub` returns a sub-string of your string from the position that you require it to.

```lua
local received_message = "video some music video"
local query = "video"

-- First parameter is the starting position, we actually want the position that our word ends at, so we ignore the start position by '_'.
local _, len = string.find(received_message, query)

-- Sub-string is zero indexed, so we must add 1 to our length.
local search = string.sub(received_message, len + 1)

print(search)
```

You can also create a function so it will be easier to use it multiple times.

```lua
function search_query(message, query)
    local _, len = string.find(message, query)

    return string.sub(message, len + 1)
end

-- Usage:
print(search_query("video some music video", "video"))
```